# Afnetworking 3.0 total Bytes Expected To Write return -1

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

i want to configure progress bar but my url can not give me total size of my image . i follow this tutorial http://tarikfayad.com/afnetworking-downloading-files-with-progress/

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

//Most URLs I come across are in string format so to convert them into an NSURL and then instantiate the actual request
NSURL *formattedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.wallpapers13.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Sunset-Large-Chinese-wall-Desktop-Wallpaper-HD-5250x3344.jpg"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:formattedURL];

[manager setDownloadTaskDidWriteDataBlock:^(NSURLSession * _Nonnull session, NSURLSessionDownloadTask * _Nonnull downloadTask, int64_t bytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    //CGFloat w = totalBytesWritten;
    CGFloat t = totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    //CGFloat percentageCompleted = w/t;
    NSLog(@"%f",t); // Error retun -1
}];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *download = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL * _Nonnull(NSURL * _Nonnull targetPath, NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response) {
    //
    //Getting the path of the document directory
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
    NSURL *fullURL = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"image1.jpg"];
    //If we already have a video file saved, remove it from the phone
    [self removeVideoAtPath:fullURL];
    return fullURL;
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, NSURL * _Nullable filePath, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!error) {
        //If there's no error, return the completion block
        [self completionBlock:(NSString *)filePath];
    } else {
        //Otherwise return the error block
        [self errorBlock:error];
    }
}];
[download resume];
```

Comment: If you are trying to do progress bar try: `[operation setUploadProgressBlock:...` here is the link to block code https://gist.github.com/andreortiz82/2934606

Comment: I cannot see any question in this post. What do you want to achieve, what do you need help on? Please, edit the original post!

Comment: @Nazir i want to download from server not upload . when we download we can not know how much download content . so can you help me on this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration * configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager * manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL * URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://static1.visitfinland.com/wp-content/uploads/Header_Linnunlaulu_ruska_autumn.jpg"];
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask * downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                                  progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // here you will be able to set progress to your progress view
        [yourProgressView setProgress:downloadProgress.fractionCompleted];
    });
} destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    NSURL * documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                                           inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                                                  appropriateForURL:nil
                                                                             create:NO
                                                                              error:nil];

    return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response, NSURL * filePath, NSError * error) {

}];

[downloadTask resume];
```

Comment: this solution is fine.  but it compulsory to use AFNetworking 3.0 in my project .

Comment: yes but if you will see there is used AFNetworking 3.0 with `AFURLSessionManager` here is also sample: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.

Answer (score 1):

If the `totalBytesExpectedToWrite` is -1, then you have some issues on your server configuration, because it is not responding the total size of your image.

Without the total size it's not possible to do a correct progress bar, you can only display some activity indicator (which just indicating that something it happening, but does not give a feedback when it will be finished).

I recommend to take a look your server settings (especially to setup the `Content-Length` header on the right way).

Comment: I know without total size i can not do process bar . What is the server issue ? Can you describe ?

Comment: Then what's your question though?

Comment: can you help me on server configuration in detail .  i use cpanel  so please give me detail steps